# Why do proxy commands handle errors differently

Tags: powershell, error-handling, command

For a while, I am maintaining a PowerShell [Join-Object](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) cmdlet.
In here I am creating a few proxy commands with default parameters, as `FullJoin-Object`, `Merge-Object` and `Insert-Object` as described here: [Proxy Functions: Spice Up Your PowerShell Core Cmdlets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/).
<sub>(In earlier version I was using aliases which could problems if the user creates its own aliases.)</sub>

Everything works as expected except that the error handling differs a little between the main command and the proxy command...

Taken the following [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), based on the following function:

```
Function Inverse([Int]$Number) {
    Rubbish
    Write-Output (1 / $Number)
}
```

<sub>(Where the function `Rubbish` doesn't exist)</sub>

Than I create a proxy function called `Reverse0`:

```
$MetaData = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata](Get-Command Inverse)
$Value = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
$Null = New-Item -Path Function:\ -Name "Script:Inverse0" -Value $Value -Force
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Inverse0:Number'] = 0    # (Not really required for reproducing the issue)
```

If I run the original function `Reverse 0`, I get **two** errors:

```
Rubbish : The term 'Rubbish' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ Rubbish
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Rubbish:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:3 char:1
+ Write-Output (1 / $Number)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

If run the proxy command `Reverse0` (or `Reverse0 0`), I get only the first error:

```
Rubbish : The term 'Rubbish' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ Rubbish
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Rubbish:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It seems that something like the `$ErrorActionPreference` has changed but I checked that and it appears to be the same within both functions.

Is there and explanation for the different behavior?
Is there a way to get a Proxy Command act the same as the original command with respect to error handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The code that `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create()` generates is currently (PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5) flawed**:

It incorrectly propagates *statement*-terminating errors as *script*-terminating errors, by using `throw` rather than `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)` in its `catch` blocks, causing the function to abort instantly.

If you manually correct these calls, your proxy function should behave as expected.

See [GitHub issue #10863](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10863#issuecomment-545533276); the linked issue isn't specifically about this behavior, but a change has been green-lighted, and it should include a fix for it.

In concrete terms, **for now**, you'll have to **fix the generated code manually**:

- Locate all `try` / `catch` statements that look like this:

```bash
    try {
        # ...
    } catch {
        throw
    }
```

- and replace them with:

```bash
    try {
        # ...
    } catch {
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
```